# Is there a means of tracking files as they are renamed or moved across my hard drives over times?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, filesystems

This year I made a massive transition to PowerShell and Cli tools. With massive power comes...

I can easily mass rename or pre append strings to file names and do often. That is fine.

But I write lots of Markdown documents and work on other files that "reference" media files on drives.

So if the file being "referenced" changes, the document will not longer be able to find it and so I end up with broken files.

Lets say I have a markdown file, `Chapter 3.md` that reference `Cats.mp4` and I dont read it for a whole year:

```
![](C:\Users\Ralf\Top Secret thesis\Cats.mp4)
```

Since then I have renamed `Cats.mp4`  file, its parent folder and maybe even moved it to another drive that has a entirely different folder structure.

Reading that `Chapter 3.md` document a year later I would not know where to begin with where this file is.

But lets say that file exitst somewhere entirely entact but only with a different file name and folder.

Is there then a way to identify this file through means other than a file name or parent folder?

I am contantly seeing people reference words like `Hash3`, `Checksum`, are they applicable here?

Can I instead search for such a property that this file holds that will not change?

Maybe there is a propperty windows uses to keep track of files, even as their names and locations change?

I am thinking, If I take note of such a property, then, a year later I can search for that propery instead of the filename to find specific files.

Searching speed across multiple drives is not an issue for me, I have a robust search utility, [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=9787), through it I can pretty much find any known property belonging to a file very quickly, I have a few PowerShell Modules that use Everything as a backend engine too.

Comment: Maybe apply Windows File auditing going forward, ..... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

Comment: And since you've made massive transition to PowerShell, if using the built in auditing does suffice to track the changes you seek, learning how to find that in event viewer and then extracting that from event viewer using UI and potentially PS will get you a little more advanced. The Event Viewer may purge unless you set the log file large so potentially extracting on those changes—which you'd have to narrow down—and then figure a way to parse out and extract 'change from,' 'change to', 'change date' in a more long term csv, etc. file to refer to seeing historical changes. Advanced perhaps.

Comment: Oh, the `Get-FileHash "C:\Folder\File.txt"` command for example is for file content, not the name of the files. So checksum or file hash won't work for rename of the file as it does not change that value when you change the name only.